# Ellipsis on resizable container (with Split.js)

Tags: javascript, ellipsis, split.js

I'm using Split.js to manage a splitted view, with a "sidebar" on the left and a section on the right.

[image]

```
<div id="c" class="split content">
  <div class="item">
    <span class="item-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span class="item-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span class="item-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span class="item-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Split.js make this possible but I'm experiencing problems with ellipsis on text in the sidebar. I would like to have dynamic ellipsis, I mean text that get truncated according to the current width of the sidebar, that can be changed by the user.

How to reach that?

Here is my playground for test: https://codepen.io/smartm0use/pen/eYmoZXm

Comment: You need to convert inline element to block element: `.item-text: {display: block};`

Comment: Yes, I see it works in the playground, but it doesn't work in my real code. My bad... I will try to update the playground... hang on...

Comment: `.ui.checkbox: {width: 100%}; .ui.vertical.menu: {width: 100%};`

Comment: I have updated the Codepen: as you can see setting `width: 100%` to both make the counter div go ahead.

Comment: you wanted that counter should be on the same row with label? And what you expected behaviour with a small sidebar?

Comment: Yes, ellipsis on the text and the counter on the same row.

Comment: check this https://codepen.io/Satif/pen/jOERMWy

Comment: Your are closed to what I mean! Yes, counter on the same row but attached to the right, instead of to the text... as showed here: https://codepen.io/smartm0use/pen/eYmoZXm

Comment: As you wish: https://codepen.io/Satif/pen/jOERMWy

Comment: It works even without CSS rules on `.ui.vertical.menu .item>.label` and `.ui.vertical.menu`. Anyway, thank you so much! Please add an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flex-boxes to reach this https://codepen.io/Satif/pen/jOERMWy:

```
.ui.vertical.menu {
  width: 100%;
}

.ui.vertical.menu .item.filter {
  white-space: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.ui.vertical.menu .item>.label {
  float: none;
}
```

Comment: Did you see that it works even without setting rules for `.ui.vertical.menu` and `.ui.vertical.menu .item>.label`?

Comment: Ok, even better :)